# Integral promotion

Tags: c, integer-promotion

When is it ever the case that a signed integer cannot represent all the values of the original type with regards to integer promotion?

From the text K&R, C Programming Language, 2nd Ed. p. 174

> **A.6.1 Integral Promotion**
>
> A character, a short integer, or an integer bit-field, all either signed or not, or an object of enumeration type, may be used in an
>   expression wherever an integer may be used. **If an int can represent
>   all the values of the original type, then the value is converted to
>   int; otherwise the value is converted to unsigned int**. This process
>   is called integral promotion.

This code shows the limits of the types for my system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{

    printf("CHAR_MAX: %i\n", CHAR_MAX);     
    printf("UCHAR_MAX: %i\n", UCHAR_MAX);

    printf("SHORT_MAX: %i\n", SHRT_MAX);        
    printf("USHORT_MAX: %i\n", USHRT_MAX);

    printf("INT_MAX: %i\n", INT_MAX);       
    printf("UINT_MAX: %u\n", UINT_MAX);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
CHAR_MAX: 127
UCHAR_MAX: 255
SHORT_MAX: 32767
USHORT_MAX: 65535
INT_MAX: 2147483647
UINT_MAX: 4294967295
```

The signed int type is way bigger than any of the other types, so when would it ever fall back to UINT_MAX?

Comment: The values you just printed can be different on different systems. It is just guaranteed, that a short is <= int and an int is <= a long for example. Thus, short and int could have the same size. @minitech's post is right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible for a `short int` to be the same size as an `int`, so an `unsigned short int` could not be promoted to an `int`, for example. This just isn't the case on your compiler.